# Not all arguments converted to Strings

Tags: python, sql

> cur.execute("SELECT tweet FROM tweets WHERE tweet = (%s)", (str(tweet)))
>
> Error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I am using python/psycog2 and Postgres for the database.

What exactly is the error? I am converting everything, not sure :(

Comment: What is the type of `tweet`?  From the error, it sounds like maybe Python choked on it while trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: Not everything in the world converts to a string. Say you have blob data in a field.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, tweet is varchar, I created the table like: `cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tweets (tweet varchar);")`

Comment: @AakarshMadhavan You missed the point of my question.  I'm not asking about the _column_ called `tweet`, I'm asking about the Python _variable_ called `tweet`.  What is stored inside `tweet`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
cur.execute("SELECT tweet FROM tweets WHERE tweet = (%s)", (str(tweet),))
```

> For positional variables binding, the second argument must always be a
>   sequence, even if it contains a single variable. And remember that
>   Python requires a comma to create a single element tuple

refer to [doc](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters).